# Android push group summary

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, notification, mobilepush-android, push-notification

Android automatically group notifications if there is more than 4 according to documentation (more that 1 in my Google Pixel 6). The problem is that I want to achieve custom click/grouping logic but...

I can access notification thru NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder and set a group to individual notification. But in order to [group](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/group#group-summary) it, I need to push custom summary notification on top like so:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
    notify(notificationId1, pushFromCloud1)
    notify(notificationId2, pushFromCloud2)
    notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification)
}
```

But I can't/really don't know where to do that, since notifications are manually pushed/shown by SDK.

Edit: How to solve this problem is shown here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210466/107771

Comment: Found what i needed here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210466/107771